# Combinatorics - 14 sunny/rainy days

Tags: combinatorics

I'm tasked with the following

You are looking at the weather forecast for the next 14 days. The weather can be
be either rainy or sunny. How many different possibilities for ¨
Weather reports are available with:

- without further restrictions
- exactly 3 rainy days
- exactly 3 rainy days with one sunny day after each rainy day

1.) For the first one I'd say that it's

$$
2^{14}
$$
because that's how many possibilities there are in total.

2.) Since we're choosing a subset of 3 rainy days out of the 14 days, I'd say that we would calculate it as

$$
\binom{14}{3}
$$

3.) what I'm unsure of now is the third question which I'd label as choosing a subset of 6 days in a total of 14 days. I'd argue that this is again

$$
\binom{14}{6}
$$

but this equation sounds also like it would make sense

$$
\frac{14!}{(14-6)!}
$$

Any help would be nice :)

Comment: For #3, you have three 'RS' and $14-6=8$ 'S'. A total of $11$ objects.

Comment: Why is my total reduced to 11 objects? @DanielMathias

Comment: Because three sunny days have been attached to rainy days, and are no longer separate object. You now have three 'RS' objects and eight 'S' objects to arrange.